# bootstrap linking not working with button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have properly linked the online bootstrap style sheet in html, but when I open the link, the 'Click here!' doesn't come in a button. How do I solve this?

Here's my code:
[using btn-primary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yd3zx.jpg)

This is the output:
[No button there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfVhV.jpg)

Comment: Instead of `div` use `button`

Comment: It should work with a div as well - just tried

Answer (score 0):

set `button` not `div`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

see here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

**BUT IT WORK WITH DIV check if you have bootstrap script**

```html
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="btn btn-primary">Primary</div>
     
</div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

To get the button, the `<button>` tag is used. And type is set on the basis of necessary like button, submit.

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary Button</button>
</div
```

For further detail, you can visit to https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp

Answer (score 0):

It should work with a div as well as button or anchor tag just try.

```
<div class="btn btn-primary">Primaray</div>
```

OR

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
```

OR

```
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</a>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19756891)